# postal code boundaries for Yukon Territory, Canada

Tags: geospatial, postal-code, canada

can you download spatial data representing postal code boundaries for Yukon Territory, Canada?

Comment: Have you tried geonames.org, openstreetmap.org and the other standard sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [location datasets page for Canada](http://index.okfn.org/place/canada/postcodes/) on OKFN's [global open data index](http://index.okfn.org/) seems to contain a pretty comprehensive yet short review on the state of postcode data:

> Canada Post is a Crown corporation of the Government of Canada. Commercial use of Canada Post's Postal Code Address Data (PCAD) product has been quoted at $50,600 per year. Canada Post claims copyright in its database of postal codes. It has recently [Apr 2012] defended its claim by [filing a lawsuit against Geolytica](https://cippic.ca/en/copyright/geolytica-statement-of-defence) [...]

The lawsuit seems to be still ongoing. And: the operator of Geolytica seems to still offer a [download of a crowd-sourced postal code dataset](http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1) for Canada (polygon, ESRI shapefile format, last updated Sep 2015), licensed under [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/ca/).

However, I had a cursory look on the postcode polygons in that file. It might need *a bit* of processing before being ready to be used:

[image: small excerpt of Canada postcode shapefile polygons]

UPDATE TO accepted answer

Legal News, May 2016 - In regards to Canadian Postal Code data on Geocoder.ca: Canada Post commenced court proceedings in 2012 against Geolytica Inc. for copyright infringement in relation to Geolytica Inc.'s Canadian Postal Code Geocoded Dataset and related services offered on its website at geocoder.ca. The parties have now settled their dispute and Canada Post will discontinue the court proceedings. The postal codes returned by various geocoder interface APIs and downloadable on geocoder.ca, are estimated via a crowdsourcing process. They are not licensed by geocoder.ca from Canada Post, the entity responsible for assigning postal codes to street addresses. Geolytica continues to offer its products and services, using the postal code data it has collected via a crowdsourcing process which it created.